# How to convert datetime stamp to unix time in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, unix-timestamp

I need to convert a datetime stamp to Unix time. I understand that this is not the easiest thing to do nor a common thing to do, but I need to do it. I have been searching for how to do this for a few hours.

Comment: Googling for 5 seconds shows how to **[go](http://www.epochconverter.com/)** the **[other direction](http://www.chrisedwards.ws/2007/01/19/crystal-reports-converting-unix-time-stamp/)** in Crystal Reports, so maybe use that info to search further?

Comment: @dg99 Thanks for the help! Your links helped me find other pages that eventually led me to the right answer. Nice one! You deserve a Klondike bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that you can use `datediff("s", date("1970-01-01 00:00:00"), {date_column})` to get the unix time stamp in Crystal.