# Date to Number conversion in Crystal Reports 2016

Tags: crystal-reports

So I checked the existing questions here and the help inside Crystal Reports 2016 before I decided to ask.  I'm an accountant who is starting to delve into Crystal Reporting for my company and am a novice.  So please be kind lol

So when using the Date (number) you can type in a number that adds to the start date inside Crystal Reports of Dec 30, 1899 per the help explanation.  So in their example:
Date(50)
//Returns the following:  2/18/1900

What I'm trying to do is have a formula that takes the Date and converts it into that unique number inside Crystal Reports.  I.e. the inverse of the above.
Looking for:
AppropriateFunction(2/18/1900)
//returns corresponding number from December 30, 1899 (in this case 50)

I'm sure there's an easy function that does this, but I can't find it or know the appropriate terminology to find it.

Comment: I guess you need to write logic that does this calculation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert datetime stamp to unix time in Crystal Reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435775/how-to-convert-datetime-stamp-to-unix-time-in-crystal-reports)